# Cannot retrieve data from PHP array, which is returned by a function() that uses JQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this "click Listener" that calls and sends a userId parameter to the function-"getModalData" which then returns an array value to the variable-"arrayedUserData".

```
$('body').on('click', '.openModal', function () {
        var userId = $(this).val(),
            btnText = $(this).text(),
            btnClass = '',
            colorCode = '',
            arrayedUserData = getModalData(userId);

        if (btnText === "Delete") {
            btnClass = 'danger';
            colorCode = '#d9534f';
        } else {
            btnClass = 'warning';
            colorCode = '#f0ad4e';
        }

        $('#actionBtn').removeClass().addClass('btn btn-' + btnClass).text(btnText);
        $('#modalTitle').text('Confirm ' + btnText);
        $('#S-modalbody p').text('Are you sure you want to ' + btnText + ' user: ');
        $('#S-modalbody h4').css('color', colorCode).text(userId + " - " + arrayedUserData.LastName + ", " + arrayedUserData.FirstName);

    });
```

This is the function-"getModalData". The returned php array from the Ajax's "success" will then be passed to the variable-"UserData" that is then returned by the function.

```
function getModalData(passedUserId) {
        var UserData;
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "get/get_modal_data.php",
                data: { passedUserId: passedUserId },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                   UserData = data;
                }
            }
        );
        return UserData;
    }
```

this is the "get_modal_data.php".

```
<?php
    include "../includes/connect.php";

    if (isset($_POST['passedUserId'])) {
        $UserId = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['passedUserId']);

        $getUserData = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tblUserAccounts WHERE uaUserId = '".$UserId."'");
        $uaRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getUserData);

        $UserDataArr = array("UserId" => $uaRow['uaUserId'],
                     "EmailAddress" => $uaRow['uaEmailAddress'],
                     "FirstName" => $uaRow['uaFirstName'],
                     "LastName" => $uaRow['uaLastName'],
                     "BirthDate" => $uaRow['uaBirthDate'],
                     "Address" => $uaRow['uaAddress'],
                     "Gender" => $uaRow['uaGender'],
                     "ContactNumber" => $uaRow['uaContactNumber'],
                     "BloodTypeId" => $uaRow['uaBloodTypeId'],
                     "AccountStatus" => $uaRow['uaAccountStatus'],
                    );


        echo json_encode($UserDataArr);
        exit();
    }
?>
```

this error appears on the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'LastName' of undefined    get_user_accounts.js:66

this is the line 66 of get_user_accounts.js, which is present on the "click listener".

> $('#S-modalbody h4').css('color', colorCode).text(userId + " - " + arrayedUserData.LastName + ", " + arrayedUserData.FirstName);

but, I am confused because the php array appears on the browser's Network Response:

> Successful Connection{"UserId":"1","EmailAddress":"paulanselmendoza@gmail.com","FirstName":"Paul Ansel","LastName":"Mendoza","BirthDate":"1998-12-17","Address":"Phase 1B Block 8 Lot 20 Olivarez Homes South, Sto. Tomas, Binan City, Laguna","Gender":"Male","ContactNumber":"2147483647","BloodTypeId":"0","AccountStatus":"ACTIVE"}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: You’re returning data from an async function so indefined gets returned. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Please get the source of `include "../includes/connect.php";`

Comment: You are getting your response as a string. Are you calling `JSON.parse(arrayedUserData)` somewhere and did not post it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `getModalData` fucntion return the `UserData` before it asign by ajax(`UserData = data;`). use a callback function:

**using callbacks**

```
function getModalData(passedUserId,callback) {
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "get/get_modal_data.php",
                data: { passedUserId: passedUserId },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                   callback(data);
                }
            }
        );
    }


$('body').on('click', '.openModal', function () {
    var userId = $(this).val(),
        btnText = $(this).text(),
        btnClass = '',
        colorCode = '';

    getModalData(userId, function (arrayedUserData) {

        if (btnText === "Delete") {
            btnClass = 'danger';
            colorCode = '#d9534f';
        } else {
            btnClass = 'warning';
            colorCode = '#f0ad4e';
        }

        $('#actionBtn').removeClass().addClass('btn btn-' + btnClass).text(btnText);
        $('#modalTitle').text('Confirm ' + btnText);
        $('#S-modalbody p').text('Are you sure you want to ' + btnText + ' user: ');
        $('#S-modalbody h4').css('color', colorCode).text(userId + " - " + arrayedUserData.LastName + ", " + arrayedUserData.FirstName);
    });
});
```

Comment: @PaulAnselMendoza your welcome, and check out Promise, it's the new way to do this

Answer (score 1):

Did you see that you get: `Successful Connection` before the JSON data? You have to remove that, if not it will be an invalid JSON response. The code you have shared doesn't have the particular stuff.

I believe you have to check your database connection, where on successful connection, it is set to output `Successful Connection`, which breaks your response. Please remove that bit of code.

```
include "../includes/connect.php";
```

It can be something like:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect() or die("Error");
echo "Successful Connection";
```

Comment: Thank You for noticing that Mr. Praveen, all this time I thought that was displayed by the browser for the successful Ajax connection.

Comment: @PaulAnselMendoza So isn't this was the issue? Was the issue somewhere else?

Comment: Your were also correct Mr. Praveen, the echoed "Successful Connection" makes the JSON response invalid and at the same time I was not using the callback method for my function that causes it to return the value before it was assigned by AJAX.

Comment: @PaulAnselMendoza Thanks! `:)`